# html2text: convert special characters

Tags: linux, command-line

So first of all, I am not talking about the python html2text but the command line tool: http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/

I am using this tool as part of my programm to generate some small text-previews for html articles.
Until now this is the line I use:

```
html2text -utf8 -nobs -style pretty filename.html
```

Unfortunately I now came across html-code that is using special characters like

```
&#xE4;
```

those don't get converted to "ä" or even "ae" like expected.

For example the line:

```
<p class="caption">Steve Ballmer, Jahrgang 56, wird zumindest auf diesem Bild auf 56 Jahre gesch&#xE4;tzt. </p>
```

should be converted to:

```
Steve Ballmer, Jahrgang 56, wird zumindest auf diesem Bild auf 56 Jahre geschätzt.
```

but produces this line here instead:

```
Steve Ballmer, Jahrgang 56, wird zumindest auf diesem Bild auf 56 Jahre gesch&#xE4;tzt.
```

The documentation says:

> By  default,  when  -nometa  is  supplied, html2text uses ISO 8859-1 for the input. Specifying this option, UTF-8 is used instead (both for input and output).

So I tried leaving out the "-utf8" and use "-nometa". But still the same result :(
Am I missing an option?

Thx for your help in advance.

Comment: The documentation also says "most constructs of HTML 4 are renderred [sic] as well, including most SGML entities, provided that they are written as "named entities" and not as a numeric value", which suggests this is a known limitation.

Answer (score -1):

did you try (html) tidy?

```
tidy filename.html | html2text -utf8 -nobs -style pretty
```

maybe including suppression of error output:

```
tidy filename.html 2>/dev/null | html2text -utf8 -nobs -style pretty
```

At least the simple paragraph in your example is completed to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content=
"HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p class="caption">Steve Ballmer, Jahrgang 56, wird zumindest auf
diesem Bild auf 56 Jahre gesch&auml;tzt.</p>
</body>
</html>
```